# How to change local host for testing site in different environment

Tags: php, host

I'm sure this has been asked and answered before, however, I am new to the lingo ad couldn't find the answer.

I have made a php site with several pages. To access the site and links on my mac, all links and photos and such must point to http://localhost:8888/ To test on my linux machine, all links and photos must point to a different local host address. And when I load the site to my web server, of course the links and photos must point to the web address.

There aren't that many places in the 5 page site that need to be changed, but I am sure there must be a better way than hand editing.

How does one change the host location globally?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on what application you are using??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for but you probably should use relative path for your links and images.
For example if you have all your images in an "images" directory in the root of your site, you should do this

```
<img src="images/myimage.png">
```

instead of

```
<img src="http://siteaddress/path/to/image/image.png">
```

This way you don't have to change anything if you change the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to have a configuration file that is specific for each environment storing the values in constants. So in your code you include the configuration file (as long as you need it) and you use the constants.

In the constants you can store values such as the connection to the database or the values of the root path/url that are specific to each environment so for example on your local machine you can have:

```
define('CONFIG_ROOT_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/');
```

whilst on the live website you might have:

```
define('CONFIG_ROOT_URL', 'http://your.domain.com/');
```

but in your code you just use:

```
$str_upload_page = CONFIG_ROOT_URL . 'upload.php';
echo $str_upload_page
//this should output 'http://your.domain.com/upload.php' on the live version
//and 'http://localhost/8888/upload.php' on your local machine
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.